# Binding component not updated after action method is invoked in JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf-2

I have built one component dynamically to meet my requirements. When click on commandlink, binding component should be updated but it is not updated. The component getter method is invoked before action method (That is in Restore_View phase). Buf after action method, getter method is not called(I mean in Render_Response phase).

Note that my backing bean scope is request.

Please find the below code of test XHTML

```
<h:form id="testForm">
    <!-- Filters Links-->
    <h:panelGroup id="dynaComp" layout="block" 
                  binding="#{testBean.panelGroup}"
                  />
</h:form>
```

And please find the below backing bean code

```
package com.kosna.test;

import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLAction;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
import javax.faces.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandLink;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * @author KOSNA
 */
@URLMapping(id = "test", pattern = "/test",
        viewId = "/faces/test.xhtml")
public class TestBean {

private HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup;

private ELContext elContext;

private int itemCount = 2;

// Constructor
public TestBean() {
    elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
}

// pretty link action method 
@URLAction(mappingId = "test", onPostback = false)
public void preparePage() {
    updateComponent();
    // include test.xhtml page;
}

private void updateComponent() {
    panelGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
    panelGroup.setId("parentPanel");
    buildMoreLink(panelGroup);
    while (itemCount >= 0) {
        HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();
        text.setId("test_" + itemCount);
        text.setValue("test" + itemCount);
        panelGroup.getChildren().add(text);
        itemCount--;
    }

}

private void buildMoreLink(HtmlPanelGroup headingGrp) {
    HtmlCommandLink link = new HtmlCommandLink();
    MethodExpression me = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
            elContext, "#{testBean.actionMethod}", String.class, new Class<?>[0]);
    HtmlOutputText outText = new HtmlOutputText();
    AjaxBehavior ab = new AjaxBehavior();
    ab.setImmediate(true);
    // I tried with appending formID also
    ab.setRender(Arrays.asList("parentPanel"));
    ab.setExecute(Arrays.asList("@this"));
    outText.setEscape(false);
    outText.setValue("More");
    link.addClientBehavior("click", ab);
    link.getChildren().add(outText);
    link.setActionExpression(me);
    headingGrp.getChildren().add(link);

}

public String actionMethod() {
    setItemCount(5);
    updateComponent();
    return "pretty:test";
}

public HtmlPanelGroup getPanelGroup() {
    if(null == panelGroup) {
        updateComponent();
    }
    return panelGroup;
}

public void setPanelGroup(HtmlPanelGroup panelGroup) {
    this.panelGroup = panelGroup;
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return itemCount;
}

public void setItemCount(int itemCount) {
    this.itemCount = itemCount;
}

}
```

Please let me know why the component is not being updated after actionMethod?

Answer (score 0):

1) Getter for the component shouldn't contain any other code. All business logic should be only in the action listener (`updateComponent()`).

```
public HtmlPanelGroup getPanelGroup() {
    return panelGroup;
}
```

2) You shouldn't create `panelGroup` manually instead use once JSF-created and always update its.

```
private void updateComponent() {
    buildMoreLink(panelGroup);
    while (itemCount >= 0) {
        HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();
        text.setId("test_" + itemCount);
        text.setValue("test" + itemCount);
        panelGroup.getChildren().add(text);
        itemCount--;
    }
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update(panelGroup.getClientId());
}
```

Perhaps, this example with component binding will be useful too: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

**EDITED**

For rendering `panelGroup` on update action you can write:

```
private void updateComponent() {
    ...
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update(panelGroup.getClientId());
}
```